# VSTS tasks failed with unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-stack

Trying to deploy VM and web app using Azure Resource Group Deployment and Azure app service tasks in VSTS CI/CDP with Azure Stack.

The task is failing with following errors:

> Error: unable to get local
>   issuer certificate

Any suggestion on this issue?

Comment: Faced similar issue, [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70952475/1176573) out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ignore SSL error set a Variable of name VSTS_ARM_REST_IGNORE_SSL_ERRORS with value: true in the release definition

Reference: [Azure App Service Task Documentation](http://%E2%80%A2%09https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeployment)

Comment: You could Accept it as an Answer, This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Comment: This is not a very good answer. Yes it fixes your immediate issue of no longer getting the error but does not address the underlying cause of the SSL error in the first place. For security reasons you should never just ignore SSL errors.