# SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate AZURE DEVOPS

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-devops, gitlab

I have a problem... My code in Gitlab, Pipeline in Azure DevOps. I use classic editor. When i start pipeline i have error "fatal: unable to access 'fatal: unable to access 'https://my.repos.example:***.git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"
Please help me!

Comment: From what I can tell it cannot verify your certificate. One thing you could do (not necessarily recommending it) is found here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-816521128.html which is to turn off the verification via git command.

Comment: yes, but in azure devops i cant do this...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: i dont understand how this can help me ? I use classic editor, and every time first step is clone repo...

Comment: I didn't know the exact answer but as you figured out it has to do with turning off verification (somehow) of the ssl verification which was what I was trying to point you to. I just knew there was at least one way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to cancel check azure devops ssl certificate, you need to go a variable group your pipeline and add GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY = 1

Comment: Although this works, but this is unsecure way of doing it. There are [some posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885449/unable-to-resolve-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-using-git-on-windows?rq=1) describe how to add `.cer` files to git store. But personally couldn't figured it out.

Comment: Does not work for my case. Still gives me a long error message in Azure Devops Server 2020 telling that secure connection couldn't be established

Answer (score 20):

For me this issue came up when attempting to clone a repository through Visual Studio 2019.  Upon selecting the Azure option in the repository menu I then picked the codebase I wanted to clone.  After this step I was prompted with an error of:

```
 "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"
```

I ran the git command setting up the global ssl backend:

```
> git config --global http.sslbackend schannel
```

And the next time I tried the steps listed above, all was well.

Answer (score 9):

> Note: You could disable SSL certificate validation in Git or tick the checkbox `accept untrusted SSL certificates`, but that is definitely not the preferred practice for security.

In my case, I had Github enterprise repository which was giving this error.
Try below steps:

1. Enable `git` to use `schannel`: `git config --global http.sslbackend schannel`
2. [Export the certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65433919/how-to-save-ssl-certificate-by-chrome-and-firefox-on-mac) from your browser in the  `Base-64 encoded X.509 (.CER)` format.

> Note: In case of windows os, you can import `.p7b` files by right clicking the > install certificates.

3. Repeat the step-2 for all the intermediate certificate chain.
4. Copy and append all the certificates as obtained above.
5. Find out the Certificate store of the `git`: `git config --list --show-scope`
   The path will be mentioned in system scope `http.sslcainfo`.
   [image: CA-cert]
6. Using a text editor (Notepad++) open `ca-bundle.crt` and copy paste the certificates from step-4 to the end of the `ca-bundle.crt` file and click Save.

Now retry the pipeline run.

Answer (score 1):

Just re-installing git worked for me. Try to uninstall and install git

Comment: By any chance are you gonna reinstall it each time it goes YOLO?

I do not know how many times are you forced to do this, but it kept re-appearing after each 10-15 min.

Answer (score 1):

Basically issue was git used ROOT self sign certificate (sometimes company provided CA) which is not trusted by local git bash.  Below are the steps I took to resolve the issue.

One of the eazy way is dissable ssl verify but there is a security issue as well as
I got a warning message when git clone/push etc and for that message takes few time
to do the git action.

Step 1
When installing use Native Windowns secure channel libary as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/45695638/4249715

or if you already install then change gitconfig file to below (This can be change by command line which is using *git config --system*)

[http]
sslBackend = schannel

Step 2
run `git config --global --edit` in git command and you can see below configs.

```
[http]
        sslverify = true
        sslbackend = openssl
        sslcainfo = C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Download the certificate chain and upload it to above path *sslcainfo* https://stackoverflow.com/a/60261983/4249715
i) To download certificate can do by browser by clicking lock icon and open certificate and go to *Copy to File...*, if you use windowns cer then use "DER encoded binary X.509" copy certificate to local. edit and copy and append this certificate to ca-bundle.crt file

If your still facing some slowness (My senario it was) So then add below config to the `git config --global --edit` file.

```
[credential]
        provider = generic
```